# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: How to use es6 modules in node 12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, es6-modules

From https://2ality.com/2019/04/nodejs-esm-impl.html Node 12 should support es6 modules; however, I just keep getting the error:

Question: How do I make a MVP of using es6 modules in node 12?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dynamic-es6-mod",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/index.mjs"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "globby": "^10.0.1"
  }
}
```

```
$ node -v
$ 12.6.0
$ npm run start


internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:821
  throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename);
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/dev/dynamic-es6-mod/src/index.mjs
    at Object.Module._extensions..mjs (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:821:9)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Answer (score 26):

The [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#loading-and-configuring-the-module) for the module states, that v2 should be used with require().

**There is a work around** though. Instead being imported it can be loaded asynchronously:

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
```

Comment: better choose axios and save the pain...

Answer (score 24):

All you have to do is adding the flag *--experimental-modules* that supports the new es6 import/export statement also the order is important as the following.

```
    "start": "node --experimental-modules src/index.mjs "
```

Comment: This is not correct. Doesn't work with nodejs version 12 LTS and no mention of --experimental-modules in the nodejs documentation for version 12 or 14. I think this option was a feature in development that was removed.

Comment: Yes, was a feature before nodejs v12.00 as per this article 
https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff

Comment: Worked for me with version 12.16.1, IDK why it did not work for you @Neutrino

Comment: ```import Jimp from 'jimp';``` Was causing the same issue,
```import('jimp').then((jimp) =>  jimp.read(fileBuffer))```
Thank you so much, you saved my day

Answer (score 19):

In **Node 14** I solved it with workaround.

source of workaround: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12319#issuecomment-535799024

short summary:

1. your root level `package.json` doesn't support ESM
2. subdirectory does - in `src` directory place `package.json` with `{ "type": "module" }`

PS: ESLint team can't solve it easily right now, just because of core design... :(

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this line of code in your package.json file `"type" : "module"`  You will be able to use imports statements instead of require if I get your question correctly.

Your package.json will look as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "dynamic-es6-mod",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/index.mjs"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "globby": "^10.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: too bad this breaks all other require statements...

Answer (score 3):

Solved use https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid-esm

```
import nanoid from 'nanoid-esm';
console.log(nanoid())
```

Comment: Resolved as `const nanoid = require('nanoid-esm');`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hell of a time with all this.   I'm just posting my solution repo, in hopes it helps someone else.

This imports an ESM dependency (ora) into TypeScript without using babel.
https://github.com/jason-henriksen/typescript-with-esm-no-babel-boilerplate

Comment: Hi, I think I am going through what you went through. I am unable to understand your solution. Can you please elaborate further please? Also, I haven't cloned your repo yet. Does that explains the solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `package.json` file and write `"type":"module"`, above debug like this:

```
"name": "npmmodule",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"type": "module",
```

2. Use `import` instead of `require`:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';

console.log(chalk.blue("hello world"));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `file-type`

Answer (score -1):

Use previous or older version of your installed node module. It will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Always nice to provide some additional details for an actual answer. It's a very generic answer and is more of a comment than a solution.

Answer (score -3):

**For Node.js:**

Tell Node to ignore the error.

```js
const Module = require('module')
const orig = Module._extensions['.js']
const fs = require('fs')
Module._extensions['.js'] = function (module, filename) {
  try {
    return orig(module, filename)
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code === 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM') {
      // From: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c24b74a7abec0848484671771d250cfd961f128e/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1237-L1238
      const content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')
      module._compile(content, filename)
      // --
      return
    }
    throw e
  }
}
```

Use Babel to transpile on-the-fly.

```
require('@babel/register', {
  ignore: (f) => {
    // Don't ignore the package we want to transpile.
    if (f.match('semver-regex') return false
    // Prevent babel transpiling anything else in `node_modules`.
    return f.match('node_modules')
  },
  overrides: [{
    // Set preset to be used to transpile our ESM package.
    test: /semver\-regex/,
    presets: ['es2015'],
  }]
})

// Call the rest of your code.
require('./index.js')
```

**For Webpack:**

Do similar but with Babel loaders and without the Node require hook.

Answer (score -4):

Try using npm's esm module which will support es6 (It can also be used in production).

Comment: Can you elaborate,please!

Answer (score -6):

Just need to update node:

run: nvm install 15
nvm use 15

credit:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUkCszM2gvU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUkCszM2gvU