# Node.JS read-pkg-up bumps into Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, es6-modules

I am using `node:latest` to run test and bumps into the following error:

```
./node_modules/.bin/nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text ./node_modules/.bin/mocha tests --timeout 10000 --recursive --check-leaks --exit  --reporter mocha-junit-reporter --reporter-options mochaFile=test_reports/mocha/test-results.xml
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /root/workspace/node_modules/read-pkg-up/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /root/workspace/node_modules/read-pkg-up/index.js from /root/workspace/node_modules/test-exclude/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename /root/workspace/node_modules/read-pkg-up/index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /root/workspace/node_modules/read-pkg-up/package.json.

    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/workspace/node_modules/test-exclude/index.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated. https://github.com/sindresorhus/read-pkg-up/issues/18

Comment: you have to adding the flag `--experimental-modules` that supports the new es6

Comment: How / where to add? Is this a hack? What's root cause of this?

Comment: `package.json` => `"type": "module"` hope it will work

Comment: Or, you can read form here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169793/error-err-require-esm-how-to-use-es6-modules-in-node-12

Comment: `package.json` => `"type": "module"` doesn't help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[ERR\_REQUIRE\_ESM\]: How to use es6 modules in node 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169793/error-err-require-esm-how-to-use-es6-modules-in-node-12)