# Js: Can't import object from external file with node-fetch imported

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch, module.exports

I have some credential saved in a file called `secrets.js`, in the same folder of the `main.js` file.
In the `secrets.js` file I wrote this:

```
const secrets = {}
secrets.key = "..."
secrets.discord = "..."
secrets.cityName = "..."
module.exports = secrets
```

In the `main.js` file I wrote this:

```
const secrets = require('./secrets.js')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function main(){
    console.log(secrets)
}

main()
```

If I execute the code i get this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1216
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: ./weather/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of ./weather/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from ./weather/main.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from ./weather/node_modules/node-fetch/package.json.

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1216:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (./weather/main.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

But if I comment this line `const fetch = require('node-fetch')`:

```
const secrets = require('./secrets.js')
//const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function main(){
    console.log(secrets)
}

main()
```

then it works and I get the expected output:

```
{ key: '...', discord: '...', cityName: '...' }
```

It appears that importing node-fetch is the cause of the error.
I am using the v16.10.0 of node.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you try to use Babel? you can also see post of [Armeen Harwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169793/error-err-require-esm-how-to-use-es6-modules-in-node-12)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS "Must use import to load ES Module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670459/nodejs-must-use-import-to-load-es-module)