# weird Nodejs: I never use `require()`, but got an error

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, require, es6-modules

Please see [Issue](https://github.com/UniCoderGroup/utty/issues/1)

I'm very sure that neither the package and I used no `require()`, but still got an error that tells me don't use `require()`

How weird it is!

code with error:

```
import stripAnsi from 'strip-ansi';
```

error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\13931\Desktop\ucon\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js from C:\Users \13931\Desktop\ucon\src\utty.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\13931\Desktop \ucon\src\utty.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all commonjs modules.
```

And the most confused thing is that:
import statement is helpful everywhere except importing `strip-ansi`!

Comment: Without seeing your code, I'm not sure how we can be expected to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[ERR\_REQUIRE\_ESM\]: How to use es6 modules in node 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169793/error-err-require-esm-how-to-use-es6-modules-in-node-12)

Comment: @msanford Thanks a lot, but it is not my question.

Comment: Are you possibly coding in TypeScript and have the compile target set for ES5 or something that generates `require()` instead of using `import`?  I'd suggest you look at your generated JS code and see what it's doing.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right! OH MY GOD! I copied tsconfig.json from somewhere I've forgotten, and it has module:"commonjs"!!!!!!!Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: But how to fix it up?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your TypeScript config is set for an appropriate target version of Javascript and appropriate target module type that supports and will use `import` so that the TypeScript compiler will generate code that uses `import`.  If not, then it will generate code that uses `require()`.

You can always look at your compiled (plain Javascript) code and see what it is generating.